# How to set up A3TGCN2 module using batches?

Tags: attention-model, temporal, pytorch-geometric, gnn

I'm trying to use a A3TGCN2 for traffic prediction, but I've had a hard time to understand how to set it up. I thought that the way of defining this module would follow the same logic as other modules from this library, such as GConvLSTM, but apparently the A3TGCN2 module doesn't accept batched `edge_index` tensors.

The documentation states that this implementation specifically allows for the use of batched tensors, but when I try to run it with batched tensors, it simply breaks my code:

```
class MyModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self,
                 features: int,
                 out_dim: int,
                 batch_size: int,
                 periods: int,
                 device=torch.device('cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu'), 
                ):
        super(Predictor, self).__init__()
        self.features= features
        self.out_dim= out_dim
        self.batch_size = batch_size
        self.device = device
        self.periods = periods
        
        self.tgnn = A3TGCN2(
            in_channels=self.features,
            out_channels=self.out_dim,
            periods=self.periods,
            batch_size=self.batch_size,
        )
        
    def forward(self, x, edge_index):
        '''
        Parameters
        ------------
        x: torch.Tensor
            node features, of shape (seq_len, num_nodes*batch_size, features)
        edge_index: torch.Tensor
            edge_indices, of shape (2, batch_size*num_edges)
        '''

        seq_len, num_nodes, features= x.shape
        x = torch.movedim(x, 0, -1)
        x = x.reshape(self.batch_size, -1, features, seq_len)
        
        # now x is shaped (batch_size, num_nodes, features, seq_len)


        H = self.tgnn(X=x, edge_index=edge_index)

        return H
```

The documentation states that x must be of shape (batch_size, num_nodes, features, seq_len), but this doesn't seem to work properly, as I'm yielding the following error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[49], line 80
     78     features = encoder(x, edge_index)
     79     features = GRLayer(features)
---> 80     y_pred   = pred(features, edge_index, batch)
     83     loss = criterion(y_pred, y)
     84 total_loss += loss

File ~\anaconda3\envs\t4c\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py:1501, in Module._call_impl(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1496 # If we don't have any hooks, we want to skip the rest of the logic in
   1497 # this function, and just call forward.
   1498 if not (self._backward_hooks or self._backward_pre_hooks or self._forward_hooks or self._forward_pre_hooks
   1499         or _global_backward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks
   1500         or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):
-> 1501     return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
   1502 # Do not call functions when jit is used
   1503 full_backward_hooks, non_full_backward_hooks = [], []

Cell In[48], line 32, in Predictor.forward(self, x, edge_index, batch)
     29 print(x.shape)
     31 # edge_index = self.unbatch_edge_index(edge_index, batch)
---> 32 H = self.tgnn(X=x, edge_index=edge_index)
     33 print(H.shape)
     35 return H

File ~\anaconda3\envs\t4c\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py:1501, in Module._call_impl(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1496 # If we don't have any hooks, we want to skip the rest of the logic in
   1497 # this function, and just call forward.
   1498 if not (self._backward_hooks or self._backward_pre_hooks or self._forward_hooks or self._forward_pre_hooks
   1499         or _global_backward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks
   1500         or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):
-> 1501     return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
   1502 # Do not call functions when jit is used
   1503 full_backward_hooks, non_full_backward_hooks = [], []

File ~\anaconda3\envs\t4c\lib\site-packages\torch_geometric_temporal\nn\recurrent\attentiontemporalgcn.py:155, in A3TGCN2.forward(self, X, edge_index, edge_weight, H)
    152 probs = torch.nn.functional.softmax(self._attention, dim=0)
    153 for period in range(self.periods):
--> 155     H_accum = H_accum + probs[period] * self._base_tgcn( X[:, :, :, period], edge_index, edge_weight, H) #([32, 207, 32]
    157 return H_accum

File ~\anaconda3\envs\t4c\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py:1501, in Module._call_impl(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1496 # If we don't have any hooks, we want to skip the rest of the logic in
   1497 # this function, and just call forward.
   1498 if not (self._backward_hooks or self._backward_pre_hooks or self._forward_hooks or self._forward_pre_hooks
   1499         or _global_backward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks
   1500         or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):
-> 1501     return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
   1502 # Do not call functions when jit is used
   1503 full_backward_hooks, non_full_backward_hooks = [], []

File ~\anaconda3\envs\t4c\lib\site-packages\torch_geometric_temporal\nn\recurrent\temporalgcn.py:229, in TGCN2.forward(self, X, edge_index, edge_weight, H)
    214 """
    215 Making a forward pass. If edge weights are not present the forward pass
    216 defaults to an unweighted graph. If the hidden state matrix is not present
   (...)
    226     * **H** *(PyTorch Float Tensor)* - Hidden state matrix for all nodes.
    227 """
    228 H = self._set_hidden_state(X, H)
--> 229 Z = self._calculate_update_gate(X, edge_index, edge_weight, H)
    230 R = self._calculate_reset_gate(X, edge_index, edge_weight, H)
    231 H_tilde = self._calculate_candidate_state(X, edge_index, edge_weight, H, R)

File ~\anaconda3\envs\t4c\lib\site-packages\torch_geometric_temporal\nn\recurrent\temporalgcn.py:188, in TGCN2._calculate_update_gate(self, X, edge_index, edge_weight, H)
    187 def _calculate_update_gate(self, X, edge_index, edge_weight, H):
--> 188     Z = torch.cat([self.conv_z(X, edge_index, edge_weight), H], axis=2) # (b, 207, 64)
    189     Z = self.linear_z(Z) # (b, 207, 32)
    190     Z = torch.sigmoid(Z)

File ~\anaconda3\envs\t4c\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py:1501, in Module._call_impl(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1496 # If we don't have any hooks, we want to skip the rest of the logic in
   1497 # this function, and just call forward.
   1498 if not (self._backward_hooks or self._backward_pre_hooks or self._forward_hooks or self._forward_pre_hooks
   1499         or _global_backward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks
   1500         or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):
-> 1501     return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
   1502 # Do not call functions when jit is used
   1503 full_backward_hooks, non_full_backward_hooks = [], []

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\torch_geometric\nn\conv\gcn_conv.py:210, in GCNConv.forward(self, x, edge_index, edge_weight)
    208 cache = self._cached_edge_index
    209 if cache is None:
--> 210     edge_index, edge_weight = gcn_norm(  # yapf: disable
    211         edge_index, edge_weight, x.size(self.node_dim),
    212         self.improved, self.add_self_loops, self.flow, x.dtype)
    213     if self.cached:
    214         self._cached_edge_index = (edge_index, edge_weight)

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\torch_geometric\nn\conv\gcn_conv.py:100, in gcn_norm(edge_index, edge_weight, num_nodes, improved, add_self_loops, flow, dtype)
     98 row, col = edge_index[0], edge_index[1]
     99 idx = col if flow == 'source_to_target' else row
--> 100 deg = scatter(edge_weight, idx, dim=0, dim_size=num_nodes, reduce='sum')
    101 deg_inv_sqrt = deg.pow_(-0.5)
    102 deg_inv_sqrt.masked_fill_(deg_inv_sqrt == float('inf'), 0)

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\torch_geometric\utils\scatter.py:74, in scatter(src, index, dim, dim_size, reduce)
     72 if reduce == 'sum' or reduce == 'add':
     73     index = broadcast(index, src, dim)
---> 74     return src.new_zeros(size).scatter_add_(dim, index, src)
     76 if reduce == 'mean':
     77     count = src.new_zeros(dim_size)

RuntimeError: CUDA error: device-side assert triggered
Compile with `TORCH_USE_CUDA_DSA` to enable device-side assertions.
```

and additionally, using `TORCH_USE_CUDA_DSA` the following error is also displayed on my console:

```
C:\actions-runner\_work\pytorch\pytorch\builder\windows\pytorch\aten\src\ATen\native\cuda\ScatterGatherKernel.cu:145: block: [73,0,0], thread: [63,0,0] Assertion `idx_dim >= 0 && idx_dim < index_size && "index out of bounds"` failed.
```

What's exactly the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Analyzing the output of the error, it seems that we are reaching out of a tensor's bounds when creating a tensor (i.e. we are passing a size that's to big for our tensors). What I have realized is that since we are changing the way to pass the `x` tensor (we are separating the `batch_size` and `num_nodes`, we should also modify the `edge_index` tensor so that it has a shape that makes sense for the proposed `x` graph. Assuming that `edge_index` is static (meaning it doesn't change for every element of the batch), we can unbatch it using the method:

```
    def unbatch_edge_index(self, edge_index, batch):
        # Calculate the number of nodes in each graph
        num_nodes_per_graph = torch.bincount(batch)

        # Calculate the cumulative sum of nodes to determine the boundaries
        cum_nodes = torch.cumsum(num_nodes_per_graph, dim=0)
        cum_nodes = torch.cat([torch.tensor([0], device=self.device), cum_nodes])

        # Split the edge_index for each graph
        edge_indices = []
        mask = (edge_index[0] >= cum_nodes[0]) & (edge_index[0] < cum_nodes[1])
        edge_subset = edge_index[:, mask]
        # Adjust node indices to start from 0 for each graph
        edge_subset[0] -= cum_nodes[0]
        edge_subset[1] -= cum_nodes[0]

        return edge_subset
```

In this case, we should then add `batch` as a parameter for the `forward` method of the model:

```
    def forward(self, x, edge_index, batch):
        '''
        Parameters
        ------------
        x: torch.Tensor
            node features, of shape (seq_len, num_nodes*batch_size, features)
        edge_index: torch.Tensor
            edge_indices, of shape (2, batch_size*num_edges)
        batch: torch.Tensor
            batch tensor (tensor that delimits the edge indices of each batch),
            of shape (batch_size*num_edges)
        '''

        seq_len, num_nodes, features= x.shape
        x = torch.movedim(x, 0, -1)
        x = x.reshape(self.batch_size, -1, features, seq_len)
        
        # now x is shaped (batch_size, num_nodes, features, seq_len)

        # now we unbatch the edge_index tensor
        edge_index = self.unbatch_edge_index(edge_index, batch)

        H = self.tgnn(X=x, edge_index=edge_index)

        return H
```

And also instantiate the `batch` tensor when calling the batch:

```
for databatch, i, _ in source_dataloader:
    for city, data in databatch.items():
        x, edge_index, y, batch = data.x, data.edge_index, data.y, data.batch
        ...
```